# Contador de minutos en PHP

Tags: php

**Temporizador en PHP**
Como medir el tiempo transcurrido desde que presionó un botón de un formulario 
    hasta que presionó otro

```
<?php

session_start();

$inicio=date('h i s');
$_SESSION["inicio"] = $inicio;
echo  $_SESSION["inicio"];

$fin=date('h i s');
$_SESSION["fin"] = $fin;
echo  $_SESSION["fin"];

$dif=$fin - $inicio;
echo $dif;

?>
<forn action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="inicio" value="inicio">
<input type="submit" name="fin" value="fin">
</forn>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Marta, bienvenida a SOes. Te recomiendo echa un vistazo a como hacer un [mcve] para que puedas incluir el código con el cual lo estas intentando. Creo que asi obtendras una buena respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Por qué con PHP? eso lo puedes hacer fácil con Javascript. Me huele a tarea para mañana... Que llevas hecho @Marta

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta y añade ese código a tu pregunta inicial.

Comment: Tengo eso armado pero no funciona y no puede ser en javascript la tarea lo pide en php.

Comment: PHP trabaja del lado del servidor, por lo tanto nunca va a saber cuando se presiono uno u otro, pero se puede solucionar con peticiones Ajax desde el cliente

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.Me piden un contador para saber cuando se tarda el usuario en resolver un juego, y que use sessiones y la función date().

Comment: Si, pero como dice @JuankGlezz no sabemos a que le esta dando click, es imposible saberlo, lo puedes hacerlo con AJAX y PHP

Comment: Necesita Ajax?? no puede guardar el inicio en una variable de sesion, y cuando se acabe tomar el valor del fin y comparar el tiempo transcurrido? @AlbertoSiurob

Comment: El formulario no sabe a que le diste click ni que estas enviando, no esta haciendo nada eso. El botón es submit, envia campos, pero no estas enviando nada.

Comment: Pero cuál inicio @gbianchi el input es submit, y el action no dirige a nada..

Comment: tal vez su problema sea el form. Antes de darle una solucion que no le sirve, porque ni siquiera sabemos si OP sabe usar ajax, no conviene que aclare si ese es el form real o solo una prueba?

Comment: en un comentario, particularmente le estan pidiendo que use sesiones.. con lo cual, se podria tomar el tiempo en el load del form.. y luego en el submit calcular el tiempo transcurrido?

Comment: No estoy seguro de si obligatoria mente necesite ajax? es decir no se puede tomar el ultimo valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se que es tarea escolar... pero me mordía de la lengua que algunos dicen que no se podía hacer sin usar AJAX...

La prueba existente que se puede hacer **SIN** AJAX :p

En el código esta comentado la lógica....

```
<?php


session_start();

// Primero controlamos si el método del envío es POST
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {       

    // Chequeamos si el botón inicio se ha presionado
    if ( isset( $_POST['inicio'] ) && $_POST['inicio'] == 'inicio' ) {

        // Creamos una variable cual me indica que era el primer intento
        $_SESSION['primer_intento'] = true;

        $inicio = date('h:i:s');

        $_SESSION["inicio"] = $inicio;

        echo  $_SESSION["inicio"];      

    }   

    // Aquí chequeamos si la variable del primer_intento está puesta y si es true
    // y también chequeamos si el botón "fin" se ha presionado o no
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['primer_intento'] ) && $_SESSION['primer_intento'] === true && isset( $_POST['fin'] ) && $_POST['fin'] == 'fin' ) {       


        $fin = date('h:i:s');

        $_SESSION["fin"] = $fin;

        // Y por último calculamos la diferencia en minutos
        $inicio = strtotime($_SESSION["inicio"]);
        $fin = strtotime($_SESSION["fin"]);
        echo round(abs($fin - $inicio) / 60, 2). " minutos";

        // Ponemos false para que vuelva a presionar el botón de "inicio"
        $_SESSION['primer_intento'] = false;
    }
}

?>
<!-- Es <form> no <forn> -->
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="inicio" value="inicio">
    <input type="submit" name="fin" value="fin">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias.Eso es lo que tenia que hacer

Answer (score -1):

Esto te debe servir, no lo podrás hacer con PHP sólamente, aquí te dejo un ejemplo con AJAX.

```
//EN HTML
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="button" id="inicio" class="myBtn" value="inicio">
  <input type="button" id="fin" class="myBtn" value="fin">
</form>

<script>
  $(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.myBtn',function(){//DETECTAR CUANDO SE DE CLICK
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'inicio')//IDENTIFICAR A QUE SE LE DIO CLICK Y SACAR SU ID Y METERLO AL VALOR QUE SE ENVIARA
        var valor = 'inicio';
      else
        var valor = 'fin';


        //CONEXION CON AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url:'dameTiempo.php',//LE DAMOS UNA RUTA DONDE ESTA EL ARCHIVO QUE PROCESARA LA PETICION
          method:'POST',
          data:valor:valor,//LE ENVIAMOS LOS VALORES
          success:function(resp)
          {
              alert(resp);//LO QUE NOS RESPONDA EL PHP LO METEMOS EN UN ALERT
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>


//EN PHP
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['inicio'] = 0; //INICIAMOS LA VARIABLE EN 0
$_SESSION['fin'] = 0;


$valor = $_REQUEST['valor']; //RECUPERAMOS EL VALOR QUE LLEGO POR AJAX


if($valor == 'inicio')//DEPENDIENDO DEL VALOR QUE LLEGO SE LO ASIGNO A MI VARIABLE DE SESION
  $_SESSION['inicio'] = $valor;
else
  $_SESSION['fin'] = $valor;

$newTime = ($_SESSION['inicio'] - $_SESSION["fin"])/60; //HACEMOS EL CALCULO
echo round(intval($newTime));//REGRESAMOS EL VALOR REDONDEADO Y EN ENTEROS PARA QUE SEAN MINUTOS


?>
```

Comment: Gracias pero no puedo usar Ajax, no se usarlo, recién me estoy iniciando en éste mundo de Php